# React native get API endpoint always 400 without body

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch, axios

I have a CURL request which is working properly:

```
curl -v -X POST https://auth.domain.com/v1/oauth/tokens -u test:test -d "grant_type=authorization_code" -d "code=d9a473a4-e417-4dd7-9151-83e9c1cb9ca6" -d "redirect_uri=app://authorize"
```

I tryed to implement it in my React Native app but I always get 400 error. Firstly I used axios:

```
var url = `https://auth.domain.com/v1/oauth/tokens`
axios.post(url, {
  "grant_type": 'authorization_code',
  "code": code,
  "redirect_uri": 'app://authorize',
},{
  auth: {
    username: 'test',
    password: 'test'
  }
}).then(response => {
  console.log(response);
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
  throw error
});
```

But I got 400 error:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Request failed with status code 400
Error: Request failed with status code 400
```

I tryed it with fetch either:

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic '+btoa('test:test'), 
  },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "grant_type": 'authorization_code',
      "code": code,
      "redirect_uri": 'app://authorize',
    })
  }).then(response => {
    console.log('Request core...');
    console.log(response);
  })
```

I got 400 error with the same empty body. For the CURL request I got 200 OK and the response from the server. What am I doing wrong in the JS side?

Comment: You are sending urlencoded data using curl. Other examples send json.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Yury Tarabanko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351705/yury-tarabanko) mentoined the problem was *"You are sending urlencoded data using curl. Other examples send json. "*

Solution:

```
var url = `https://auth.domain.com/v1/oauth/tokens`
axios.post(url, 
  querystring.stringify({
    "grant_type": 'authorization_code',
    "code": code,
    "redirect_uri": 'app://authorize',
  }),{
    auth: {
      username: 'test',
      password: 'test'
    },
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  }).then(response => {
    console.log('Request core...');
    console.log(response);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**This code Work for me.**

```
.catch((error) => console.log( error.response.request._response ) );
```